# How to post html form data to controller using ruby on rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using ruby on rails 3.1. And am trying to post html form data to controller for saving the record in database. But I am getting routing error like this 'No route matches [POST] first/save' .But when I tried to run this link in address bar like '127.0.0.1:3000/first/save' it is working fine. Can any one please tell me where am doing wrong.

My routes are like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 

  root 'first#hello'


  get 'first/save'

end
```

And my html form is like:

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" method='post' action='/first/save'>

        <label for='S.No'>S.No</label> 
            <input type="text" name="s_no" placeholder='Enter s. no.'> 
        <label for='name'>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name='name' placeholder='Enter your name'> <br>
        <label for='seller_id'>Seller ID</label>
            <input type="text" name='seller_id' placeholder='Enter your seller ID'> <br>
        <label for='email'>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name='email' placeholder='Enter your email'> <br>
        <label for='img_url'>Image</label>
            <input type='text' name='img_url' placeholder='Enter your image url'> <br>
            <input type="submit" name='save' value='Save'>
    </form>
```

And here is my controller:

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController

  def save
    @name = params[:name]
    @email = params[:email]
    @seller_id = params[:seller_id]
    @img_url = params[:img_url]
    @s_no = params[:s_no]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do POST requests, instead of

```
get 'first/save'
```

you should have

```
post 'first/save'
```

Comment: using post in showing the error 'ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in FirstController#save'
@ Marek Lipka

Comment: @Randhir it's a material for another question. If you wish to disable checking authenticity token, you should add `config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false` line to `application.rb` file.

Comment: skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token  add this to start of the controller.

Comment: @Randhir Rorschach's suggestion is better if you want to disable checking authenticity token only for this controller.

Comment: Yes,I implemented Rorschach's suggestion.